# How to grab titles from webpages using Beautiful Soup in Python and iterating through

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 in python to parse web pages and get information. I am having trouble grabbing just the title. Another part I struggled with was following the links, should this be done recursively or would I be able to do it through a loop?

```
def getTitle(link):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find("<title>"))
```

Comment: Link to scrape?

Comment: Use `print(soup.find('title').text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import urllib    

def getTitle(link):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
    return soup.title.text

print(getTitle('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news'))
```

Which displays:

```
Home - BBC News
```